# Delete-orphan is giving exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, all-delete-orphan

Hi i have Department entity ,In that department entity I have property's called department name In string datatype and another property **parentdepartment** as department datatype(Class Type) as the foreign key to that column.And I have used one-to -one relation ship and cascade type is orphan-delete.If delete My parent department I don't want to delete child department for that reason I have used orphan-delete here but it is giving an exception as following.
**Exception**

```
SEVERE: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`department`, CONSTRAINT `FKA9601F72A15DD2FD` FOREIGN KEY (`parentdeparment_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`))
Mar 14, 2014 9:48:49 AM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.myapp.struts.Teast.main(Teast.java:20)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`department`, CONSTRAINT `FKA9601F72A15DD2FD` FOREIGN KEY (`parentdeparment_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`department`, CONSTRAINT `FKA9601F72A15DD2FD` FOREIGN KEY (`parentdeparment_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1980)
    ... 11 more

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.myapp.struts.Teast.main(Teast.java:20)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`department`, CONSTRAINT `FKA9601F72A15DD2FD` FOREIGN KEY (`parentdeparment_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`department`, CONSTRAINT `FKA9601F72A15DD2FD` FOREIGN KEY (`parentdeparment_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1980)
    ... 11 more
Java Result: 1
```

**DeparmentEntity**

```
  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.myapp.struts;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
//import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
//import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

/**
 *
 * @author hyva
 */
@Entity
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String departmaentname;
    private String daperthead;
    @OneToMany
    @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Set<Department> parentdeparment = new HashSet<Department>();

    public boolean addDepartment(Department d) {
        return parentdeparment.add(d);
    }

    public String getDepartmaentname() {
        return departmaentname;
    }

    public void setDepartmaentname(String departmaentname) {
        this.departmaentname = departmaentname;
    }

    public String getDaperthead() {
        return daperthead;
    }

    public void setDaperthead(String daperthead) {
        this.daperthead = daperthead;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Department)) {
            return false;
        }
        Department other = (Department) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.myapp.struts.Department[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    public Set<Department> getParentdeparment() {
        return parentdeparment;
    }

    public void setParentdeparment(Set<Department> parentdeparment) {
        this.parentdeparment = parentdeparment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong here, does one department have only one parentdepartment? If you are deleting parentdepartment, first remove all the references in the department table, i think many other rows has reference to the parentdepartment which you are trying to delete, that could be the reason. Try to see the department table, ifany other row has this parentdept id. If so, you may have to use many to one relation instead of one-one

Comment: Hi i have Updated my code can u please see above

Comment: I'm trying to undrstand your data model. does he department have more than one parent? or is it the other way around?

Comment: No Here One Child department has one parent department. But parent department will have many child's.Has same as One class has a many student.